# Solaris 11 and nfs idmapping

Tags: solaris, nfs

A simple problem
With Solaris 11 I create a nfs share

```
zfs set share.nfs=on rpool/public
```

my Linux client mount it..

```
mount solaris2:/var/public /mnt/share
```

I want to give write access to myuser, i know three solutions

Solution 1: chmod 777

```
chmod 777 /var/public #NO COMMENT
```

Solution 2: made the uid identical between remote and local system

change the uid of my local Solaris user to the uid on remote Linux user and then give an acl, this is ok if you have one user only, is simply awful in a multiuser system (you have to replace all old uids with the newest!)

Solution 3: Mapping the uid of remote user to a local user and then give the acl

```
idmap add remoteuser@remotehost unixuser:myuser
chmod A=user:myuser:add_file/read_data/execute/write_data/execute:allow /var/public
```

but doesn't work.
The local user can write data to /var/public, the remote not, why?

Edit1: idmap command as I understand translate gid/uid to SID, is useful with AD or LDAP

Edit2: on [illumos](https://illumos.org/man/8/share_nfs) they have put some interesting options
uidmap and gidmap, only one problem: Solaris11 is not a Illumos "distro" and those options simply don't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for a better solution this workaround is fine: create a group with the same gid on client and server, then made the acl.

On client (Linux)

```
groupadd -g 10093 nfs-users
usermod -aG nfs-users myuser
```

on server (Solaris)

```
groupadd -g 10093 nfs-users
usermod -G nfs-users myuser
```

Then I add the acl to the shared zfs set (is mounted on /var/public)

```
chmod A+group:nfs-users:write_data/append_data/execute/add_file/add_subdirectory:allow /var/public
```

Testing: works fine, all users (remote, and locals) which belong to nfs-users group can write on share.
A better solution was to use AD (or samba4) + idmap, but this workaround play fine also in local files environment.